# Word order after a "perché" subordinate clause

Tags: word-order

> Woman: Perché dovrei fidarmi di te?
>
> Man: **Perché** di me si fida la duchessa, **perché** anch’io sono diverso, **perché** queste faccende sono il mio pane quotidiano...

I'm trying to understand the correct word order in a "perché/because" subordinate clause. It seems that a preposition like "di" or an adverb like "anch’io" comes first.

And then I wonder why in the first clause, the subject "la duchessa" comes last, whereas the subject in the third clause "queste faccende" comes first?

Comment: Where do these sentences come from?

Comment: Note that “anch'io” is the subject: “io” is a pronoun and “anche” is an adverb modifying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After *perché* any kind of clause, with any ordering, can occur, as if they were main clauses. The three sentences in your example are all acceptable as main clause.

*Queste faccende sono il mio pane quotidiano* is a normally-ordered sentence (a subject with a nominal predicate).

*Di me si fida la duchessa* has a slightly unusual ordering instead; the standard form would be *La duchessa si fida di me* (The duchess trusts me). The sentence as given seems to stress that the duchess trusts especially the speaker (so the person he is speaking to should too). And this sentence works the same exact way both as a main clause and as a subordinate clause after *perché*, while on the other hand “Perché la duchessa si fida di me” would be a perfectly good answer, with a different stress.

So, in principle, any sentence, either standard or with an unusual construction to stress something can also be a *perché*-sentence, and even a composite period (“Perché dovrei fidarmi di te?” “Perché se non ti fidi, mi rivolgo a qualcun altro”).

Comment: In the 2nd clause, is it possible to say "perché sono diverso anch’io" or "perché sono anch’io diverso"?

Comment: Yes, they would be perfectly fine.